# Assign myClass object to UIView object and using myClass selectors(variables)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I try to assign myClass object to `UIView` class object and using myClass variables.

So,

I created myClass that contains units segment control

```
@interface myClass : UIView
@property (nonatomic,readonly) UISegmentedControl *units;
```

In my `UIViewController` I try to do something like this

```
myClass *newObject = [[myClass alloc]init];

UIView *newView;

newView = newObject;

[[newView units] addTarget:self action:@selector(changeUnit) 
                      forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and I received "No visible `@interface` for `UIView` declares the `selector` 'units'"

Is it possible to do not use `myClass *newView = [[myClass alloc]init];` object?

Answer (score 2):

Well, thanks to Objective-C's flexibility it is possible to do what you're asking although it is a strange requirement.

This line of code: `[[newView units] addTarget:...]` shouldn't generate any complier errors (unless you've set the "Treat Warnings as Errors" flag to YES) but it will generate a warning. As long as the `newView` variable is in reality an instance of `myClass` everything will work as expected.

There are also some precautions you can take like using the `respondsToSelector:` and `isKindOfClass:` methods. Here is a way you can make your code more robust:

```
myClass *newObject = [[myClass alloc] init];

UIView *newView = nil; // always initialize method variables to nil

newView = newObject;

// make sure 'newView' can respond to the 'units' selector
if ( [newView respondsToSelector:@selector(units)] )
{
    // if it does, use 'performSelector' instead of calling the method
    // directly to avoid a compiler warning
    id unitsObject = [newView performSelector:@selector(units)];

    // make sure the object returned by 'performSelector' is actually
    // a UISegmentedControl
    if ( [unitsObject isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]] )
    {
        // if it is, cast it...
        UISegmentedControl *units = (UISegmentedControl*)unitsObject;

        // ... and add the Target-Action to it
        [units addTarget:self action:@selector(changeUnit) 
                  forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}
```

Just remember

- To correctly initialize the 'units' property inside 'myClass' or to correctly assign it before using it
- When you instantiate the 'newObject' variable you're calling 'init' instead of the default initalizer 'initWithRect:'. Make sure this is the intended behavior.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm always glad to see advanced hacking answers to newbie questions :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to accept answer if this was useful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is OOP basics. Your `newView` is a `UIView`, which doesn't have `units`.

Your subclass `myClass` has `units`.

Just use `[[newObject units] addTarget...(etc)]`.

Comment: Yes, thats true I knot how to do this in proper way. But I asked that is it possible to using unit when you assign myClass object to UIview object.

Comment: I just don't understand why you want to cast it to a UIView... Your myClass is a UIView, because you subclassed it.